# Grab URL from element on page for Bitly URL shortening

Tags: javascript, shopify, bit.ly

I'm working in shopify - attempting to do this client-side

I have a URL being generated (based on what items are in the cart presently) that adds items to the cart based on their ID#.

I'm building this little thing for our sales team, so they can start an order for a customer and send that arrangement to someone through a URL - right now in shopify if you do it their way it will take the customer to the checkout window and they can't edit that order - This way we're just sending an arrangement in the cart that they can adjust before they actually check out.

So right now, that url gets very very long depending on how many items are in the cart, and I'd like to use bit.ly to create a short url based on that generated url - I have it now so that it can encode the URL so it won't have any strange characters in it - but looking at the bitly api documentation most of the examples seem generic and other cases on stack overflow seemed to be specific to their problem --

Perhaps it can't be done? Thanks for taking the time to read this, if anyone has any suggestions at all - or if you think I just missed a big chunk of something obvious please feel free to tell me so. I can provide code for what I have so far if that makes it easier to understand what I'm trying to do!

#### screen shot of what that page looks like

[image: screenshot]

---- ADDING CODE BELOW ----

```
// get the cart
if (typeof Shopify === 'undefined') var Shopify = {};
Shopify.cart = {{ cart | json }};
Shopify.idsInCart = [];
Shopify.quanInCart = [];


//where we gonna put the url
var cartURL = document.getElementById('cart_url');

// for every item in Shopify Cart - push to idsInCart and print the IDs to the cart url
for (var i=0; i<Shopify.cart.items.length; i++) {
  Shopify.idsInCart.push(Shopify.cart.items[i].id);
  cartURL.innerHTML += 'id[]=' + Shopify.idsInCart[i] + '&';  
}
// get the div with cartURLform as an id
var longUrlNode = document.getElementById('cartURLform'),
    // grab the .textContent from that div
    textContent = longUrlNode.textContent;

// 
var uri = longUrlNode.textContent;
var res = encodeURI(uri);



// Copy to clipboard example
document.querySelector("#qlink").onclick = function() {
  // Select the content
  document.querySelector("#qlink").select();
  // Copy to the clipboard
  document.execCommand('copy');
};



(function(long_url,callback){
  bi = new URL("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?");
  var params = [
    "login=__obviously__",
    "domain=bit.ly",
    "apiKey=__obviously__",
    "longUrl="+ encodeURIComponent(long_url)
  ]
  bi.search = "?"+params.join('&')
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        callback(res["data"]["url"]);

        //           document.getElementById("qlink").value = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);


      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET",bi.toString());
  xhr.send(null)

})(res,function(a){

  //       prompt("hello", a);
  document.getElementById("qlink").value = a;

});
```

--- Edited to add code

Comment: So you do not know how to call the bit.ly api to generate the url? Why not just make your own keys on your site that holds the url?

Comment: I can read the documentation but it hasn't helped me figure out how to do what I'm trying to do. I can't figure out how to tell it "Use this dynamically generated url and then make a short one based on it"

Comment: So you generate an api key and you call the service with the url as a parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't help me at all

Comment: I have an api key that was assigned by bitly already ... so i got that going for me

Comment: https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/dynamically-use-bitly-in-your-site-easiest-way/

I found this example from 2010 that grabs the url of the current page - but I can't find what 'first_result' is supposed to be, or why sss is the variable, or how I'd modify it for this specific case.

Comment: And ... eventually I put 2+2 together.

Comment: And of course, this works fine on everything except for Safari. Anyone know any reasons BitlyCB wouldn't work on safari? That's the error I get - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BitlyCB --  Just gonna leave this here I guess.

Comment: Draft Orders might be a better solution! https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/create-orders

Comment: @kallen27 firstly, are you sure the bitly script is loading? Looking at the documentation, it says the method described in the link you shared is deprecated.

Comment: @CameronHurd -- Pretty sure 'draft orders' are for taking payments and sending secure check out links. I'm trying to create an editable cart that just gets a customer started with a cart when they've been invited (typically our account managers are populating a cart with items they know their customers may be interested in) - From what the AMs tell me they want a link with arrangements that aren't fixed and can be changed, draft orders don't create an editable cart, no?

Comment: @HymnZ Pretty sure it is deprecated - Open to other suggestions

Comment: @kallen27 There is an error according to the link you have shared. The current "latest" version of the API generates a different response. You'd need to modify the code to work with the current response. If you are unable to solve it, you can update the post with the code you are using for a final answer.

Comment: Yeah I don't disagree but v4 of bitly's api doesn't show any code examples ... So